# back button on RTL applications: right side or left side

Tags: usability, android, rtl

We're workin' on a messaging application in our language (Persian), Persian is an RTL language and we reflect some default android buttons like "back" btn, in common msg application like "Telegram" or any common msg app the "back" btn float on the left side of header and at the bottom, in msg text field the "send" icon floated in right side.
when we're have to make the application flow in Right-to-left arrange, how we can do some thing like this without hurting usability and user-experience (users' usually find the "send" btn on the right side of "msg text field")
and another question is: Can we use the back and forward (functions like submit, send or...) btn on the same side in a seqment?

sorry for my bad English

Comment: https://material.io/guidelines/usability/bidirectionality.html#

Answer (score 1):

I think the UI elements should be in their English position because your users are engaging with a ton of apps that don't have the Persian language support.

So the core UI elements should stay like the English versions.

Comment: There's a problem: We've a "back btn" on the left side (Using EN direction) and an "Right to left title" that starts from left on the header of app. This is **THE MESS**